# Two random variables with Poisson distribution, compute $[X-Y=0]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Solution:
$P= \sum_{k=0}^\infty P[X=k]P[Y=k]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}= e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda\mu)^k}{k!}=e^{-(\lambda + \mu)\lambda\mu}$

Someone gave me advice that I can solve it like this, but I don't understand really why and why I can't do it this way:

$P[X-Y=0]=P[X-k=0]=P[X=k]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

This was my idea, but my friend couldn't explain to me, why I can't choose this approach.

Comment: $Y$ is not $k$... it's not any particular value, it is a random variable.

Comment: $P[X-Y=0|Y=k] \neq P[X-Y=0]$... i.e., replacing $P[X-Y=0]$ by $P[X-k=0]$ is like conditionning by $Y=k$.

Comment: See Skellam distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Provided $X,Y$ are independent, then 
\begin{align}P(X=Y)&=E(I(X=Y))=E(E(I(X=Y)\mid Y=y))\\
&=E(e^{-\lambda_X}\lambda_X^Y/Y!)=\sum_{y=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda_X}\lambda_X^y/y!\cdot e^{-\lambda_Y}\lambda_Y^y/y!\end{align}

Comment: What is $I(X=Y)$ I know what it is expected value, but I don't understand $I()$

Comment: @Muffy it is called the indicator function, whose expectation is exactly the event it indicates.

Comment: Thank you, I know about indicator function, now it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

> Someone gave me advice that I can solve it like this, but I don't understand really why and why I can't do it this way:
>
> $P[X-Y=0]=P[X-k=0]=P[X=k]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

Because $P[X-Y=0]$ is not generally equal to $P[X-k=0]$, and in any case, where did this unbound constant, $k$, come from?

You transformed the random variable $Y$ into some arbitrary constant $k$ without any justification at all.

What you want to do is actually:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X-Y=0) ~&= \mathsf P(X=Y) \\ &= \mathsf P(\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty (X=k\cap Y=k)) && \text{Note how $k$ is bound to the scope of the union} \\ &=~ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=k \cap Y=k) && \text{and now to the scope of the series} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=k)~\mathsf P(Y=k) && \text{due to independence}\\ &~~\vdots~\end{align}$$